# Order a data table based on two different columns

Tags: r, datatable, data-cleaning

I have trouble to find a fitting solution to my problem. My dataset has multiple companies and time-series data. In order to do calculations, I, therefore, need to order the data into the correct ordering. I want the data to be ordered by one column which is a number, and then by a second column which is a date in ascending order.

Imagine the data looks like this:

```html
$gvkey   $datadate
11111    02/01/2010
22222    03/01/2010
22222    02/01/2010
11111    03/01/2010
11111    01/01/2010
22222    01/01/2010
```

Here an example of how I want my data to look:

```html
$gvkey   $datadate
11111    01/01/2010
11111    02/01/2010
11111    03/01/2010
22222    01/01/2010
22222    02/01/2010
22222    03/01/2010
```

So basically I want R to order first according to "gvkey" column and afterward according to "datadate" column (which is in date format) in ascending order (oldest to newest). The dataset includes many more columns too.

I hope I was able to explain my newbie-problem and hope someone has a hint for me. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: if you are referring to the `data.table` package, you can check out `?setkey`

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- df[order(gvkey, datadate),]
```

I believe you just need to provide the order of columns.